# How identify Layer name when removing it from legendInterface qgis?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I am trying to connect the removing layer action with a slot for doing some processing after that.
I already try this:

```
QObject.connect(self.iface.legendInterface(), SIGNAL("itemRemoved()"),self.RemoveScenario)
```

but i need to identify the removed layer name.
anyone have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QgsLegendInterface.itemRemoved()` signal can reference any legend item, e.g. group or layer, which represents a `QTreeWidgetItem` removed from the `QTreeWidget` legend.

To specifically connect a `slot` with the action of layers being removed, or about to be removed, use a signal from the [`QgsMapLayerRegistry` class instance](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerRegistry.html), e.g.:

```
void  layersWillBeRemoved (QStringList theLayerIds)
  Emitted when one or more layers are removed from the registry.

void  layerWillBeRemoved (QString theLayerId)
  Emitted when a layer is removed from the registry.

void  layersRemoved (QStringList theLayerIds)
  Emitted after one or more layers were removed from the registry.

void  layerRemoved (QString theLayerId)
  Emitted after a layer was removed from the registry.
```

**Side note**: you may wish to start using the [PyQt4 new-style connection syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), e.g.:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().layersWillBeRemoved["QStringList"].connect(self.RemoveScenario)
```

**Edit**: to get the name of the layer from such a connection, in your slot you can do:

```
lyr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(lyr_id)  # returns QgsMapLayer pointer
lyr_name = lyr.name()  # or .originalName()
```

where `lyr_id` is a map layer id from the `QStringList` passed by the signal. See [`QgsMapLayer` class docs for more details](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html).